# Javascript to detect when a Note, Task, Call or Activity is added on a Dynamics CRM form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there a way to detect when a Note, Task, Call or Activity is added on a Dynamics CRM 2015 form using Javascript?

The form OnSave event does not seem to trigger when these associated records are created:

[image: User adding note to form (e.g. Case form)]

When a new Note, Task, Call or Activity is added on the form, what script would allow for a prompt to be opened to confirm the addition of the new child record?

Answer (score 4):

The social pane is not customizable, so you can't connect JavaScript events to it.

So you can't create a prompt to confirm the save of a note or a task when it's added by the social pane.

Comment: Thanks Guido, will have to try something creative to get this working